# Issues with text input control (Text area )in asp.net and HTML Decoding

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to incorporate a responsive jquery input control for inputting blogs, which will be saved to database, from then retrieved to web form page.

I am facing issues with the input text control as entries made through it are hijacking my blog slider itself when I render them through repeater in the front page of my website.

When I derive simple plain textx it works fine, when I even derive this HTML encoded text also it works fine but the moment I add `.ToSubstring()` function to the eval method it starts acting up, breaks down my slider itself. conflict ?

Here is my code

```
<%#System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("Content").ToString().Substring(0,180)) %>
```

Here is the HTML Encoded text

```
<div class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify;">Our last pilgrimage to <a href="http://www.sigandur.in/" target="_blank">Sri Chowdeshwari Temple</a> at Sigandhur (Karnataka) was in <a href="http://kartourism.blogspot.com/2009/01/sigandhur-tourism.html">2009</a>. It was time to revisit the temple and offer our prayers. We knew very well about the perils of visiting the temple on a holiday, yet we undertook the pilgrimage as we had a packed schedule.</div>
```

This is how slider breaks when added with .ToSubstring() method 
[image: Slider]

**Can anyone help me in solving this problem ?** or **suggest me a better text input control**, which doesn't conflict with users code. Thank you

Here is my slider code too

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="height: 260px; background-color: #EEEEEE">
    <h3 style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Blogging my Thoughts <span>
        <img style="height: 35px; width: 35px" src="images/home/pen.png" />
    </span></h3>

    <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <asp:Repeater ID="RepDetails" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="item <%# (Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "active" : "") %>">
                        <div class="testimonial-section">

                            <h3 runat="server" id="fh"><%#Eval("Heading") %></h3>
                            <p runat="server" id="fp">
                                <%#System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("Content").ToString().Substring(0,180)) %>

                            </p>
                            <br />
                            <a href='<%#String.Format("{0}", Eval("Seo"))%>' style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px">Continue Reading </a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

            <ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators-set">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are making `.Substring(0,180)` but the encoded text is more than 180, it is 463 character,
so the `<div>` tag is opened and didn't closed because the closing tag `</div>` is after the 180 characters

---

i think that you have to display all encoded text or you have to display some other content without html tags.